# How to send queryParam with hashmap object

Tags: java, api, rest-assured

I trying to hit this api in post with java and restassured. But api has alot of `queryParam` with contentype- application/x-www-form-urlencoded, which cannot be send manual changing it.

Sample code is as follows-

```
RequestSpecification request=given();
        Response responseSample = request
                .queryParam("lastName","Sharma")
                .queryParam("firstName","Sobhit")
                .queryParam("street","523-E-BROADWAY")
                .post(url);
```

I have multiple parameters for sample added 3. I want read it from hashmap object and send it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RestAssured API provides multiple methods to send parameters using `java.util.Map`. Create new map and put there parameters you need:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("param1", "value1");
params.put("param2", "value2");
```

Then add this map to your request specification as:

1. Form parameters:

   ```
   RestAssured.given()
       .formParams(params)
       .when()
       .post("http://www.example.com");
   ```
2. Query parameters:

   ```
   RestAssured.given()
       .queryParams(params)
       .when()
       .post("http://www.example.com");
   ```
3. Path parameters:

   ```
   RestAssured.given()
       .pathParams(params)
       .when()
       .post("http://www.example.com/{param1}/{param2}");
   ```

Also there's a generalized method `params(parametersMap: Map): RequestSpecification`, but it adds parameters as query or form params depending on request specification.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code with:

```
RequestSpecification request=given();

// add the request query param
map.forEach((k, v) -> {request.queryParam(k,v);});

// send the request
Response responseSample = request.post(url);
```

Comment: I am giving a try to this but how to read multiple params keys & it values ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `rest-assured v3.0.3` we can do this:

```
// Put the query params in a map.
Map<String, String> queryParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
queryParams.put("lastName","Sharma");
queryParams.put("firstName","Sobhit");
queryParams.put("street","523-E-BROADWAY");

// Pass the map while creating the request object.
RequestSpecification request=RestAssured.given().queryParams(queryParams);
Response responseSample = request.post(url);
```

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
  <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: it is a post request for which I am try with x form data. I dont think the above answer will help. @jacobcs

Comment: Are you looking to send form params? If so you can use `formParams`methods and pass the same map and do a post.

Comment: Formparams I can use but not able to create an object for it, as I have lot of keys and values which I dont want to hard code.

Comment: Where do you have it stored outside of the application? An excel/json/property file? you got to create a logic to read the outside file and convert to a map and use it later in the rest-assured call.